# when configuring Azure file sync between a azure file share and an on-premise server can this be done with private link?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Trying to configure azure file share between and on-premise file server and azure file share but am unsure about how to make it secure.  We will be using express routewith private peering to connect onpremise to azure.   Do we need to configure express route peering, private endpoints (storage account>networking>disable public access>create private endpoint?). When trying to configure the private endpoint the configuration is asking for a vnet but the on-premise server is not on a VNET?  All traffic needs to stay internal and cannot traverse public endpoint hence why I am looking at the private endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express Route with private peering then your connection to Azure files from on-premises  will go over Express Route and not over the internet, but it will still go to the public IP of the storage account.

If you want to route traffic to a private IP for the storage account then you need to setup Private Endpoints. As you say, you cannot add a private endpoint to your on-premises network, but what you can do is add a private endpoint to an Azure vNet that is connected to your on-premises network using Express Route and then setup your on-premises DNS to use the private IP of the storage account. This will then route traffic over Express Route to the vNet and the private IP of the storage account.